# Qual diferença entre TRUNCATE e DELETE + CHECKIDENT?

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Ambos realizam a mesma ação (deletar + zerar o valor da PK), mas em performance qual a diferença entre elas?

*Exemplo:* Quando se tem mais registros é recomendado usar qual forma?

**TRUNCATE**:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Exemplo
```

**DELETE + CHECKIDENT**:

```
DELETE FROM Exemplo
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Exemplo, reseed, 0);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Em termos de performance `TRUNCATE` é mais eficiente. O principal motivo para isso é que o comando não escreve linha por linha deletada no log de transações. No caso do SQL Server o comando também já reseta o contador de colunas identidade conforme você percebeu.

O comando `DELETE` é mais lento e seguro (você tem a segurança de poder fazer `rollback` todas as vezes). Outra particularidade do SQL Server é que, por questões de integridade de dados, não é possível executar o comando `TRUNCATE` contra uma tabela referenciada por uma *foreign key*, nesse caso o jeito é executar um `DELETE` (ou então desabilitar a *constraint*).

O comando `DELETE` requer permissão para `DELETE`, o comando `TRUNCATE` requer permissão para `ALTER`.

---

**Referência:** [MSDN - Truncate Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177570(v=sql.110).aspx)