# Como avaliar qual comando usar entre truncate/delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu estava lendo sobre esses comandos  `Truncate table` e `Delete from`, onde vi essa explicação

> **Truncate table** - Este comando remove a marca d’agua da tabela limpando
>   a mesma para uma próxima utilização.
>
> **Delete from** - Porem este comando não remove a marca d’agua da tabela
>   mantendo a mesma do mesmo tamanho caso seja um delete full.

Não entendi o que se refere a essa marca d'agua.

A minha dúvida é, como avaliar e quando/qual comando usar? E qual deles já zeram campos `identity`

Comment: se vai apagar a tabela toda, usa truncate, caso contrário, delete, acho que nenhum vai resetar a sequencia da pk

Comment: @IgorCarreiro: Marca d'água, ou high water mark, é um conceito utilizado no Oracle Database.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual diferença entre TRUNCATE e DELETE + CHECKIDENT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26461/qual-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-truncate-e-delete-checkident)

Comment: As perguntas são bastante semelhantes. Acredito que se diferem pois o AP daqui pergunta qual zera as colunas `identity`.

Comment: @vnbrs tem razão

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É sempre bom recorrer à documentação oficial ou mais confiável possível.

O [`TRUNCATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql) remove todas as linhas de uma tabela. Não gera logs de exclusão das linhas de forma individual. Essa é uma forma mais rápida, já que não gera logs de transação. Se a tabela contém uma coluna idenity, seu seed será zerado. Vale ressaltar que é um comando de **definição** de dados, DDL.

O [`DELETE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql) remove as linhas de uma tabela com base numa condição imposta. Caso não tenha imposto uma condição, excluirá todas as linhas da tabela. Aqui, é um comando de **manipulação** de dados, DML.

Ao não aplicar uma condição para o `DELETE` ele se mostrará mais lento que o `TRUNCATE`. O `DELETE` passa linha a linha deletando os valores e o `TRUNCATE` não.

Se o propósito for deletar **todas** as linhas, use `TRUNCATE`. É mais rápido, consome menos recursos e foi feito para isso. A Microsoft define isso como uma boa prática [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql#best-practices).

Comment: Somente como complemento: TRUNCATE não pode ser utilizado em algumas situações, conforme consta na documentação. Uma dessas situações é quando a tabela contém coluna que seja referenciada por restrição presente em outra tabela (FOREIGN KEY).